# Word Association: Choose the pair that most relates to WATER : THIRST

Tags: word, word-property

Choose the best answer. The best answer will apply to the least of the others. 
***Example: As Speed is to Slow, so Rabbit is to Tortoise.***

A. Milk : White 
 B. Gasoline : Engine 
 C. Transport : Stranded 
 D. Speed : Crash 
 E. Wine : Sober

Why did you choose what you chose? Explain your reasoning.

Comment: rot13(N arrq sbe JNGRE perngrf n GUVEFG nf n ARRQ SBE FCRRQ perngrf n PENFU)

Comment: Nice thought but technically a need for speed is not a real need, and does not inevitably result in a crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the intended answer is

> C, because the second word is "having no [first word]". (But the grammar doesn't quite match up: "thirst" is a noun, and "stranded" is an adjective.)

Comment: It's hard because you have to choose the best of the available answers. This is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is -

> **E. Wine : Sober**
>  Because we drink water to not be thirsty while we drink wine, which is alcoholic, to not be sober. Both pairs are liquid and characteristics of our mind/body.

Comment: This is incorrect. Water quenches Thirst. Wine does not quench Sober. You could say, Thirst causes a need for Water. You could not say, Sober causes a need for Wine. OTHERS THAT WORK: Without Wine, you would be Sober. Without Water, you would Thirst. But, likewise, without Transport you would be Stranded. So, there is more than one answer to that, so it cannot be correct.